# extract lowest number before and after slashmark in sql

Tags: sql, extract, teradata

I have a large dataset of measurements, stored in a free text field.  I'm needing to extract the lowest systolic amount (value to left of slash) and lowest diastolic amount (value to right of slash).  I've included a sample dataset below...  As you can see, some of the records, like #2, are simple, but others are complex.   Is there anyway to do this in sql or teradata?  Any suggestions are appreciated!

```
record 1   lt 90/50 rt 128/88
record 2   left arm regular cuff 144/100
record 3   156/72;134/82
record 4   204/127,  189/122, 196/121
```

Comment: How is this stored in the database?

Comment: I think that the better way is using regular expressions in some language programing. Can you do that?

Comment: That data is not normalized and will be really hard to deal with in SQL. Can you split systolic and diastolic values into separate columns, and have a separate row for each measurement? Note that it will be easy to combine such separate fields into a single record, but it is very difficult to separate already-combined records such as what you have.

Comment: currently for the data I'm able to extract, it's being stored in one field ie 120/80. If necessary, I can break it into two fields one for systolic and one for diastolic.  JCalcines - my expression writing skills are very limited at this point.  I'm not sure how to write a string expression to account for the multiple /// in the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your TD release?

In TD14 there's a StrTok_Split_to_Table/StrTok function:

```
DROP TABLE tab;
CREATE TABLE tab (id INT, TEXT VARCHAR(200));

INSERT INTO tab(1,'lt 90/50 rt 128/88');
INSERT INTO tab(2,'left arm regular cuff 144/100');
INSERT INTO tab(3,'156/72;134/82');
INSERT INTO tab(4,'204/127,  189/122, 196/121');

SELECT id,
   MIN(CAST(STRTOK(token,'/',1) AS INT)) AS systolic,
   MIN(CAST(STRTOK(token,'/',2) AS INT)) AS diastolic
FROM 
   TABLE (STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(tab.id, tab.TEXT, ' ,;')
          RETURNS (id INT, tokennum INTEGER, token VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET UNICODE) 
         ) AS dt 
WHERE token LIKE '%/%'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

You have to check for any additional delimiters beside ' ,;' otherwise the CAST to INT will fail.

If your release is pre-TD14 the STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE can probably be replaced by a way more complicated recursive query. How many rows exist in that table and how large is the text column defined?

Edit:

This is a quick&dirty recursive query, assuming blood pressure for living people is never single or four digits :-)

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte
 (id,
  pos,
  remaining,
  token
 ) AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    POSITION('/' IN TEXT) AS pos,
    SUBSTRING(TEXT FROM pos +4) AS remaining,
    TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM (TRIM(BOTH ';' FROM (TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM (SUBSTRING(TEXT FROM pos -3 FOR 7))))))) AS token
  FROM tab
  WHERE POSITION('/' IN TEXT) > 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    id,
    POSITION('/' IN remaining) AS newpos,
    SUBSTRING(remaining FROM newpos +4) AS remaining,
    TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM (TRIM(BOTH ';' FROM (TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM (SUBSTRING(remaining FROM newpos -3 FOR 7))))))) AS token
  FROM cte
  WHERE POSITION('/' IN remaining) > 0
 )
SELECT id,
   MIN(CAST(SUBSTRING(token FROM 1 FOR POSITION('/' IN token) -1) AS INT)) AS stolic,
   MIN(CAST(SUBSTRING(token FROM       POSITION('/' IN token) +1) AS INT)) AS diasystolic
FROM cte
GROUP BY 1
```

Btw, both queries will fail if there are no numbers before/after the slash

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I use TD SQL Assistant and I tried running the script you provided, but it doesn't seem to be recognizing the StrTok_Split_to_Table/StrTok function.  When I look at the TD_SYSFNLIB, the functions aren't listed there...  I verified that I'm running TD version 14.10, db version 13.10 and provider version ODBC 14.10.  Could the db 13.10 be causing trouble?

Comment: SQLA & ODBC are 14.10, but the database version is only 13.10 :-(  I added a recursive query to split the string in 13.10

Comment: I was afraid of that. We just got the 14.0 upgrade pushed out last week...maybe the db will be upgraded soon.   Part of the query runs now; however, it still doesn't like the strtok.  Error says expected something between the word STRTOK and (.

Comment: Arghh, i forgot to remove the StrTok, fixed. Ths should run on any release :-)

Comment: This worked fantastically, dnoeth!  Thank you so much for the time and effort in helping me resolve my problem!  Never would have figured this one out on my own.